# How the values are set to the POJO classes?

Tags: java, pojo

`damagestockBean.getDamage_invoice_no()` refers to a getter method in a POJO class which looks like

```
public String getDamage_invoice_no() {
        return damage_invoice_no;
    }
```

I know that the corresponding `damage_invoice_no` variable was set by using a `setter` method.

```
public void setDamage_invoice_no(String damage_invoice_no) {
        this.damage_invoice_no = damage_invoice_no;
    }
```

But I don't know from where the above `setDamage_invoice_no` is called. Is there any simple way to find the caller?

Comment: "Find Usages" in your favourite IDE?

Comment: I'm on netbeans and I don't know what you mean by the above..

Comment: Doesn't Netbeans has a help page?

Comment: You can run your code in a debugger and add a breakpoint in the setter methods. If it stops at the breakpoint you can see in the stacktrace where the setter is called.

Comment: @Jens Well, that is really time-consuming if there are several places where that method can be called. And you can't be sure if you maybe missed a place, because it will be "used" rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IDE(Integrated Development Environment) can help you find usages in code. Example: Intellij IDEA - default keymapping is Alt+F7.

In **Netbeans** it's alt+u. Usually when you right click a method name in the IDE the find usages option should appear.

You can also use a file manager such as total commander for a quick search function within a directory where you look for `setDamage_invoice_no`.

Comment: I don't want the time. I want the place or location where the mentioned setter method was called.

Comment: Inside the default constructor?